# Adobe Fireworks CS6 maximum image dimension

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I am using Adobe Fireworks CS6, and the maximum width I can set of my image is 5900 pixels.

Attempting to resize it larger than this results in no action.

The PC I am on is high-spec.

Does Fireworks have a built-in maximum image size?

I think I will try Illustrator to get the image up to the required 10000px width.

Comment: Last time I heard, FW max size was 6000px.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a quite old [thread on Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/248564) where [speculation](http://forums.adobe.com/message/2749629#2749629) is made that it's because Fireworks is a screen-specific tool and this behavior might change in the future.

---

**However, you can change the limit.**

Make sure that Fireworks is closed, open `Fireworks CS6 Preferences.txt` file located in:

- Windows 7/Vista: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Fireworks CS6\English\`
- Windows XP: `C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Fireworks CS6\English\`
- MacOS X: `Library/Preferences/Adobe Fireworks CS6/en/`

and change

```
    <key>MaxDocSizeInPixels</key>
    <integer>6000</integer>
```

to

```
    <key>MaxDocSizeInPixels</key>
    <integer>10000</integer>
```

or adjust this number as needed.

Comment: Just as additional information, I recently tried to increase this value > 10,000 and I get a series of 'An invalid value was entered' errors in the application. I think 10,000 may be a hard limit.

Comment: Doh, just came back to my own comment 6 months later...anyone know how to open files over 10000 pixels?

Comment: WIndows 10, Fireworks CS5 - this still works.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was the only "good" answer I found online, everyone else just copped out by saying use Illustrator, which I love already and use a lot, but I needed ultra high resolution for a specific "raster" project (multiple sheet grid, which fireworks handles great). It worked fantastically on CS6 (though "Image Size" specifically has a hard limit of 10000, which is fine) and even let me set it to 12000 pixels. You are a life saver!!!