# Adobe Fireworks CS6 maximum canvas size

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I've just installed Fireworks CS6 on my Mac. In a previous version of Fireworks I was able to change the size of my canvas from the default od 6000 pixels. Since then I've upgraded to Yosemite and to CS6 but no longer seem to be able to find the Fireworks CS6 Preferences.txt file to make changes.

There was a question on this previously but the suggestion doesn't seem to work?

[Adobe Fireworks CS6 maximum image dimension](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9440/adobe-fireworks-cs6-maximum-image-dimension)

Comment: could you specify *why* the given solution didn't work? Iirc, in your original comment, the file was missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the file you are looking for can be found here:

> ~/Library/Preferences/Adobe Fireworks CS6/en/Fireworks CS6 Preferences

Note Fireworks must be closed prior to editing it. Also note that 10000 appears to be the hard limit for MaxDocSizeInPixels.